# Dynamic add/remove rows and auto calculating totals- Problem with calculation when deleting inner rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have pieced together a script I want to use to create invoices. It adds "Invoice Items" as a table row which includes checkbox, Quantity, Item, Unit Cost, and Price.

You can then check item, or use check-all option (Upper Left) to remove rows. As well as that it auto calculates row totals as well as a Sub Total for the whole "Invoice". As long as you remain linear, add items as will without removing them (unless removing all of them) it adds up fine. The issue I am having is if you remove any items in the middle it wont calculate total anymore.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vg2jsmo) too.

This is my first post and any help is greatly appreciated- Thanks in advance!!

```html
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Invoice Item" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Item(s)" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <TR>
      <TH>
        <INPUT type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" onclick="toggle(this);">
      </TH>
      <TH>Quanity</TH>
      <TH>Item</TH>
      <TH>Unit Cost</TH>
      <TH formula="cost*qty" summary="sum">Price</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]">
      </TD>
      <TD>
        <INPUT type="text" id="qty1" name="qty[]" onchange="totalIt()"> </TD>
      <TD>
        <INPUT type="text" id="item1" name="item[]"> </TD>
      <TD>
        <INPUT type="text" id="cost1" name="cost[]" onchange="totalIt()"> </TD>
      <TD>
        <INPUT type="text" id="price1" name="price[]" readonly="readonly" value="0.00"> </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</form>

Sub Total: <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="total"><br><input type="submit" value="Create Invoice">

<!-------JAVASCRIPT--------->
<script>
  function calc(idx) {
    var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost" + idx).value) *
      parseFloat(document.getElementById("qty" + idx).value);
    //alert(idx+":"+price);  
    document.getElementById("price" + idx).value = isNaN(price) ? "0.00" : price.toFixed(2);
    //document.getElementById("total") = totalIt;
  }

  function totalIt() {
    var qtys = document.getElementsByName("qty[]");
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= qtys.length; i++) {
      calc(i);
      var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price" + i).value);
      total += isNaN(price) ? 0 : price;
    }
    document.getElementById("total").value = isNaN(total) ? "0.00" : total.toFixed(2);
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByName("qty[]")[0].onkeyup = function() {
      calc(1)
    };
    document.getElementsByName("cost[]")[0].onkeyup = function() {
      calc(1)
    };
  }

  var rowCount = 0;

  function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    element1.name = "chk[]";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element3.name = "qty[]";
    element3.id = "qty" + rowCount;
    element3.onkeyup = totalIt;
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.name = "item[]";
    element4.id = "item" + rowCount;
    cell4.appendChild(element4);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element5 = document.createElement("input");
    element5.type = "text";
    element5.name = "cost[]";
    element5.id = "cost" + rowCount;
    element5.onkeyup = totalIt;
    cell5.appendChild(element5);

    var cell6 = row.insertCell(4);
    var element6 = document.createElement("input");
    element6.type = "text";
    element6.name = "price[]";
    element6.id = "price" + rowCount;
    element6.value = "0.00";
    $(element6).attr("readonly", "true");
    cell6.appendChild(element6);

  }

  function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;

      document.getElementById("select-all").checked = false;

      for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
          table.deleteRow(i);
          rowCount--;
          i--;
        }


      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $("input").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("data-selected-all")) {
      //Remove atribute to allow select all again on focus        
      $(this).removeAttr("data-selected-all");
    }
  });

  $("input").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).attr("data-selected-all")) {
      try {
        $(this).selectionStart = 0;
        $(this).selectionEnd = $(this).value.length + 1;
        //add atribute allowing normal selecting post focus
        $(this).attr("data-selected-all", true);
      } catch (err) {
        $(this).select();
        //add atribute allowing normal selecting post focus
        $(this).attr("data-selected-all", true);
      }
    }
  });

  function toggle(source) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i] != source)
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Also I need it to call the totalIt function after row removal.....

Comment: When asking a question, please do your best to insert only relevant information into your code :)

Comment: Your `price` field is read-only. Is that done purposefully?

Comment: Also, you should update total price in deleteRow method.

Comment: Yes i don't want price field edited manually, but still want the value when submitting the form.

Comment: @KodyR. Thanks for the input- I felt it all was relevant to help better understand my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs after a row in the middle is deleted due to the current code being bound to the indices that are used in html (e.g. ids like "cost1", "price1" etc).

When `totalIt` function is invoked, it tries to access rows that have been already deleted. To have this issue fixed, you can abstract from particular indices by using more broad selectors. Here is a drop in replacement `totalIt` function that does not depend on indices:

```
function totalIt() {
  var costs = document.getElementsByName("cost[]");
  var quantities = document.getElementsByName("qty[]");
  var prices = document.getElementsByName("price[]");
  var total = Array.prototype.reduce.call(costs, function(total, cost, index) {
    var price = parseFloat(cost.value) * parseFloat(quantities[index].value);
    prices[index].value = isNaN(price) ? "0.00" : price.toFixed(2);
    return isNaN(price) ? total : total + price;
  }, 0)
  document.getElementById("total").value = isNaN(total) ? "0.00" : total.toFixed(2);
}
```

Also, should you want to recompute the total on row delete - call `totalIt` in the delete handler (`deleteRow`). Note that you will likely need to wrap it in `setTimeout` so that re-computation will occur in the next event loop iteration, after the record is actually removed from DOM

Comment: This works!! Thanks- been struggling on it for days. 

Haven't actually tried to process the data yet with PHP.... am I going to have a problem with indices? For example is it going to set multiple items as cost1, price1, etc??? if so I believe it wont effect the Database as ill post the array thru a loop.... am i on the right track?

Comment: Hmm... with all the changes it does not seem to want to delete the first row now.... no big deal, but would be nice to fix.

Comment: Hi @AustinAllenCarlson, thank you for accepting the answer.
Regarding the inability to delete the first row, the issue is in this line `var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];`
It should find the `input` element, but instead it finds some text node with a new line character. I would recommend searching the input tag as follows `var chkbox = row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];` instead of using `childNodes[0]`.

Comment: As for other possible issues due to indices, cant tell much. Should you face a particular problem, it would probably make sense to open a new question. But generally, in my option, by using the same indices both in html and JavaScript, you may involuntary make presentation layer and business logic tightly coupled, which may lead to issues with the codebase maintainability.

Comment: Made those changes- it helped! @antonku as far as the indices- there is no further issue, they format into an array correctly. Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => 1.00 [1] => 4.00 [2] => 9.00 )